# Could someone explain to me what is happening in this shell script?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I understand that its going to a directory and recursively and forcefully removing ./tmp. My issue is with the "-d ./tmp". What does the -d do and why would the "./" be in front of tmp?

Thanks in advance

```
cd $WORKING_DIR

if [ -d ./tmp}; then
       rm -rf ./tmp
fi
```

Comment: -1: at least take the effort to ensure that your code sample does not contain blatant syntax errors.

Comment: If you're gonna give `rm` the `-f` flag, what's the point of checking if the thing exists? I guess it's just for the odd corner case where `./tmp` is actually a file or socket or something... Still...

Answer (score 1):

It checks whether `./tmp` exists and is a directory. In that case, it removes it.

From `man test`:

> -d FILE
>
> FILE exists and is a directory

---

By the way, the syntax has errors:

```
if [ -d ./tmp}; then
             ^
             needs space and ] instead of }
```

Correctly:

```
if [ -d ./tmp ]; then
```